# how to receive argument in COLLADA (.dae) file?

Tags: ros, collada, gazebo-simu

I am working with ROS and GAZEBO and I need to change the individual objects in the environment with help of .xacro and .dae files.

For my requirement, I need to change a .dae file as per the parameter received from the other .xacro file. But there is no such tag defined in the documentation to receive arguments or store arguments in the .dae file.

for instance, in a .xacro file, I can drive my logic with below line of code --

```
<xacro:arg name ="name" default="cylinder">
```

or in a .xsl file, we use below code--

```
<xsl:param name="new_title" />
```

A .dae file is also an XML format and I want to know how we can get store the argument in this?

Comment: I have only seen `.dae` files being used as `visual` components for `GAZEBO` and no arguments passed to it. Or do you want to load different `visuals` depending on this parameter?

Comment: yes exactly. That's my requirement. I want to load different visuals based on the parameters.

Comment: have you tried using the [xacro if else](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro)? and then depending on this param, load one `.dae` file or another?

Comment: yes. That is what I am doing now. Using xacro, I load different .dae files based on the condition. But I want to pass different parameters to .dae file from xacro so that I have to use only one .dae file.

Comment: @ignacio -- any idea if I don't want multiple .dae file and can parameterize it somehow?

Comment: no idea. I haven't seen anything like this yet